# Intermittently not receiving form emails SMTP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, smtp, cdo.message, intermittent

I run a classic asp website in which several thousand emails are sent a day through SMTP.  I use Cdo.Message.  A single "To" Email address and a Single "From" email address are used.  The majority of these messages are received; however, recently several messages each day are getting stuck somewhere (not sure where).

Logs show that users have accessed the page; therefore, the message should be sent (It is sent on page load).  There are no traces of emails not sent in any of the SMTP folders.  Where else should I look?

Comment: so how do you know they're getting stuck?

Comment: This unlikely to be a coding problem, hence this question would be best asked on Serverfault.com.  Include details of the web server and the SMTP mail agent you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Could those users be search engine robots? What does it take to get to that page? how about robotic submissions that are brute forcing their way thru?